# Update of SpamAssassin

Tags: postfix, update, spamassassin

We're running SA as a filter to Postfix and just completed an update (of SA) from 3.3.2 to 3.4.1. The spamassassin, spamd, and spamc executables have all been verified as the newer version. Additionally, the old symlinks have been repointed to the never versions. Postfix's master.cf file has been updated, as well, to pipe into the new spamc. And finally, all the services have been flushed, reloaded, and/or restarted. However, mail going through the system still contains the old header references:

```
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.3.2 (2011-06-06) on FOO
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-1.9 required=3.0 tests=BAYES_00 autolearn=ham version=3.3.2
```

Any ideas as to what we might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a followup (for the next person), the problem seems to have been an issue with the service restart process.

To fix the issue we forced a hard-stop (of S/A) following by a command-line restart:

> $ pkill -f spamd
>   $ spamd -c -d